# Sorting doubles

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I am working on a project to read data in from a text file regarding different athletes' scores at the winter Olympics.  I have successfully been able to find each country's total score by comparing each athlete with their country and adding it to a total.  Each of these totals are stored in doubles: FRA, CHN, UKR, GER, RUS, CAN, ITA, USA, JPN, and GBR.  (All representing different countries)

So now I have a bunch of values stored as doubles that I need to sort in descending order.  I know I could just put the doubles into an array and sort it, but I will lose the name of the country associated to each value.  In PHP I could simply put it into an associative array and sort it - but unfortunately I have a very poor understanding of java and don't have a clue what to do.  I would appreciate it if someone could at least point me in the right direction.

The output needs to Display the countries name and it's score in descending order.

Comment: What made you to expect the SO team to give you the solution with out any code or examples?

Comment: @tailorBird OP did get an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Score implements Comparable<Score>{

    private String country;
    private int score;

    //write getters, setters

    public int compareTo(Score otherScore){
        return otherScore.score - this.score   // for descending
            // return this.score - otherScore.score for assending

    }
}
```

You can create array of Score objects and pass it to Array.sort(array);
Now the sorting criteria for these objects are the score.

Example in detail:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: Subtracting both scores **should** be OK, but it's probably a better practice to use Java's built-in: `Integer.compare (score, otherScore)`